# Counting up and down in recursive manner in JS

Tags: javascript, recursion, functional-programming, counter

I am currenty working on functional programming techniques. There are topics about this issue **[ especially there is one about java ]** but not about JS.

I want to create **a recursive function** that can **first,** count up until the limit I decide, from the number I indicate **and then** start counting down when the limit is reached. I can already do this with a for loop but it feels like hard-coded **since i am supplying the numbers in the loop.**

Basically something like this:

```
counter(0,10);
// 0, 1, 2, 3 ... 10, 9, 8... 0
```

Here's what I thought of:

```
counter = (number, limit) => {
limit !=== 0

if ( number = limit ) {
  counter(number -1, limit -1)
  console.log(number)
} else if ( number < limit ) {
  counter(number + 1, limit + 1)
  }
}
```

Idea behind this is, if the number is lower than the limit count up, **if they are equal, decrement each argument by 1 to continue satisfying the first if condition**.

**When I run this command on v8, it gives a rangeError "maximum stack size reached".**

Also, this should not be an infinite loop.

For loop version:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 11; i++ ) { console.log(i) }
for (let i = 9; i < 11 && i > -1; i--) { console.log(i) }
```

Comment: `!===` isn't a thing in JS. Also `x = y` shouldn't go in a condition. Use `x == y` or even better `x === y` instead

Comment: @yunzen will be more careful next time. i started maybe a month ago. knew those but was too focused on the problem lol thx thou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to loop back down or decrement the value, as when you reach your base-case (the thing that stops the recursion), then you'll jump back up the calling function, which holds the previous `value`:

```
counter(0, 10) // logs: 0
    |           ^
    |           | (returns back to)
    |---> counter(1, 10) // logs: 1
              |             ^
              |             | (returns back to)
              |---> counter(2, 10) // logs: 2 <---
                        |                         | (returns back to)
                        |                         |
                        ........   ---> counter(10, 10) // logs: 10 - base case
```

Each call of `counter()` will call counter again (shown in the above diagram with the child `counter` calls), these then print their current `value`. When you reach the base case, you print the current value, and return, which causes you to pass control back to the calling function. By this I mean that when you call a function, the function will run. When the function finishes, the code picks up back from where the function was originally called:

```js
function bar() {
  console.log("bar");
}

console.log("foo"):
bar(); // call the function makes the code execution jump up into `bar` function. When that completes, our code execution jumps back to the next line, which logs "baz"
console.log("baz");
```

in our `counter()` example, the place which called the child `counter()` functions are its parent `counter` function, which we jump (pass control back to) when the child function finishes executing (returns). Once control has been passed back. to the calling function (ie: the parent function in the diagram above) you can then log the `value` of again as that contains the previous value of `value`:

```js
function counter(value, limit) {
  if(value === limit) {
    console.log(value);
  } else {
    console.log(value); // on the way down / going deeper (increment)
    counter(value+1, limit);
    console.log(value); // on the way up / coming up from the depths (decrement)
  }
}

counter(0,10);
// 0, 1, 2, 3 ... 10, 9, 8... 0
```

Comment: can you elaborate more on "and return, which causes you to pass control back to the calling function, which you can then log the value of again:" part? And where do we decrement the value? I only saw increment. Thanks btw.

Comment: @afyonkes I've updated my answer to clarify, I've added another (hidden) code snippet to try and explain things and added comments to them. I also elaborated on the answer

Comment: @afyonkes It's a function call stack: You wind it up bei calling the function recursively and than, when you reached the base case, it is unwound automatically.

Comment: @NickParsons if I understood correctly, we're "collecting" the data back when going up the diagram, instead of actually decreasing it, we just simulate it. how does the if statement recall the counter function or is it only for printing out the maximum value?

Comment: @afyonkes that's right, we're "collecting" the values back when we move back up the diagram. The if-statement doesn't "recall" the counter function though. If you see in the diagram, the only call to `counter()` which doesn't have a child is `counter(10, 10)`, this is because the if-staement executes so no more counter() functions are called. Once it finishes executing, the parent function which called it will continue it's execution and log its value (ie: `9`), this continues up the diagram (like you mentioned)

Comment: @NickParsons Your comments seem to be wrong. I think you wanted to say `on the way up (increment)` and `on the way down (decrement)`

Comment: @yunzen thanks, but when going down (ie: calling counter functions / spawning children), the `value` is incremented, which acts as the "increment" part for the values logged to the console. On the way up, we print the previous values as we revisit each function, which acts as the decreasing part of the logged output - so I think the comments are correct

Comment: @NickParsons I think, I'm right. The first `console.log` prints `0,1,2` and the second prints `2,1,0` Try `console.log('up', value); // on the way up (increment)` and `console.log('down', value); // on the way down (decrement)`

Comment: @yunzen yeah, but when I say "down" I mean move down in the diagram / create / call new children / functions. So the first `console.log` should be  `console.log('down', value); // on the way down (increment)` and the second would be `console.log('up', value); // on the way up (decrement)` (when I say "up" I mean go back up to the previous function calls -  move up in the diagram)

Comment: @NickParsons Ah, I see. It would be more obvious if you used _deeper_ instead of _down:_

Comment: @yunzen while you are going down you are incrementing because you are adding to the prior value you retrieve from the preceding functions until you reach the base case which is where the function stops. then you go up in order to simulate the log as if the code counts down but in reality it just returns the values of the preceding functions in a reverse order so his code is completely true and makes %100 sense . A very brilliant way of solving it imo, very much appreciated.

Comment: nice answer, and beautiful ascii art. i would suggest that `value > limit` is the base case and would make the function total forall `value` and `limit`. see my post for explanation.

Comment: @Thankyou - cheers, I saw your answer and I think it's great. The generator function is cool as well. I agree that it would be better to return a result rather than just log stuff to the console, I mainly stuck with the logging approach as it seemed to be what op was trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

Recursion is a functional heritage and so using it with functional style yields the best results. This means avoiding things like mutations, variable reassignments, and other side effects.

1. If start, `a`, is greater than stop, `b`, we have reached the base case. Return the empty result, `[]`
2. (inductive) `a` is *less than or equal* to `b`. If `a` is equal to `b`, return the singleton result, the "peak" of the mountain, `[a]`
3. (inductive) `a` is *less than* `b`. Recur on the sub-problem `a + 1, b` and append/prepend the result with `a`

This encodes as a pure functional expression, comments below match the numbered explanation above -

```js
const uppendown = (a, b) =>
  a > b
    ? []                                // #1
: a == b
    ? [ a ]                             // #2
: [ a, ...uppendown(a + 1, b), a ]      // #3
    
const ex1 =
  uppendown(0, 10)
  
const ex2 =
  uppendown(3,7)

const ex3 =
  uppendown(9,7)
  
console.log(JSON.stringify(ex1))
// [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0]

console.log(JSON.stringify(ex2))
// [3,4,5,6,7,6,5,4,3]

console.log(JSON.stringify(ex3))
// []
```

```js
uppenDown(3,7)
= [ 3, ...uppendDown(3 + 1, 7), 3 ]                   // #3
= [ 3, 4, ...uppendDown(4 + 1, 7), 4, 3 ]             // #3
= [ 3, 4, 5, ...uppendDown(5 + 1, 7), 5, 4, 3 ]       // #3
= [ 3, 4, 5, 6, ...uppendDown(6 + 1, 7), 6, 5, 4, 3 ] // #2
= [ 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3 ]
```

```js
uppendown(9,7)                        // #1
= []
```

---

If for some arbitrary reason you don't like chaining functional style ternary *expressions*, you can trade them for imperative style `if` *statements* -

```js
function uppendown (a, b)
{ if (a > b)
    return []                                // #1
  else if (a == b)
    return [ a ]                             // #2
  else
    return [ a, ...uppendown(a + 1, b), a ]  // #3
}
    
const ex1 =
  uppendown(0, 10)
  
const ex2 =
  uppendown(3,7)

const ex3 =
  uppendown(9,7)
  
console.log(JSON.stringify(ex1))
// [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0]

console.log(JSON.stringify(ex2))
// [3,4,5,6,7,6,5,4,3]

console.log(JSON.stringify(ex3))
// []
```

---

If you want the numbers to come out one-by-one instead of returning an array, you can use JavaScript's generators. Notice the striking similarity between each program variant -

```js
function* uppendown (a, b)
{ if (a > b)
    return                                  // #1
  else if (a == b)
    yield a                                 // #2
  else
    ( yield a                               // #3
    , yield *uppendown(a + 1, b)            //
    , yield a                               //
    )
}
    
for (const x of uppendown(3, 7))
  console.log(x)
  
// 3
// 4
// 5
// 6
// 7
// 6
// 5
// 4
// 3
```

Comment: Nice!  I saw this, decided  that the answers here would fine and I didn't have anything to add to the discussion.  But this answer actually adds a lot.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this?

```js
console.clear();
{
  "use strict"
  
  // Curry function
  const nextStepInit = start => max => {
    let increment = 1;
    let counter = start;
    
    return () => {
      counter += increment;
      if (counter >= max) {
        increment = -increment;
        return max;
      }
      if (counter <= start) {
        return start;
      }
      return counter;
    }
  }
  
  // this is a function, because nextStep(start)(max) returns a function
  const nextStep = nextStepInit(0)(10)
  
  const output = result => document.getElementById('output').value = result
  
  const onClick = () => output(nextStep())
  
  output(0)
  
  document.getElementById('next-step').addEventListener('click', onClick)
}
```

```html
<button id="next-step">Next Step</button><br>
<input id="output" disabled/>
```

Comment: i guess this is not a recursive function as you commented in the code but thanks. i didnt proceed to currying yet but its in the line.

Comment: This is not recursive, that is true. Bit IMHO your original task doesn't make much sense to be solved by recursion anyway. The problem with most courses introducing recursion is that they don't give you tasks that make sense

Comment: problem is just an example. recursion is a very delicate technique which i like very much. it is something like a core logical notion independent of software developing.

Comment: @yunzen This is opinion based. Recursion is a tool just as general as imperative loops to handle iterative tasks. Claiming a task isn't suitable for recursion implies it isn't suitable for imperative loops either.

Comment: @scriptum I didn't mean to imply that recursion is a bad concept. What I meant was that the most task that are give in programming courses to teach you recursion don't make sense. They are not real life examples where anyone would use recursion in the first place, but plain old iterations with loops.

Comment: this example is convoluted beyond words. this question is tagged with `recursion` and `functional-programming` and the answer uses neither. Make not mistake, senselessly currying a function doesn't make it "functional".